# Get Frequency for Audio Input on iPhone

Tags: ios, signal-processing, fft

How can I get the frequency for an audio input on iPhone? Is it necessary to use a FFT if I'm only interested in finding a specific frequency (i.e. within a timeframe of x milliseconds, check if there is a peak at y Hz)?

Comment: See my answer to the same question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19966776/468812][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19966776/468812

Answer (score 4):

If you're just interested in a specific, fixed frequency (i.e. a pure tone) then you can use the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) which is very simple to implement and relatively lightweight (computationally) compared to an FFT.

Comment: Also, to determine if the output of the Goertzel filter is actually a peak, one should compare that output to a computation of the average power over the same time interval.  A big percentage of that average power suggests a peak.